# Unsigned script from Internet can be run under RemoteSigned execution policy

Tags: powershell

I have downloaded a script from the Internet. Under the current "RemoteSigned" execution policy, this script should not run. But, it does run. Why is that?

```
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Type-Get-exported-fee19cf7
```

Windows knows it is from the Internet because of the Zone.Identifier ADS.

```
PS H:\src\test> Get-Item .\Get-Type.ps1 -Stream *

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::H:\src\test\Get-Type.ps1::$DATA
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::H:\src\test
PSChildName   : Get-Type.ps1::$DATA
PSDrive       : H
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : H:\src\test\Get-Type.ps1
Stream        : :$DATA
Length        : 4631

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::H:\src\test\Get-Type.ps1:Zone.Identifier
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::H:\src\test
PSChildName   : Get-Type.ps1:Zone.Identifier
PSDrive       : H
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : H:\src\test\Get-Type.ps1
Stream        : Zone.Identifier
Length        : 26

PS H:\src\test> Get-Content .\Get-Type.ps1 -Stream Zone.Identifier
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

My execution policy is set to RemoteSigned, but the function can be loaded without error. Why does this not produce an error?

```
PS H:\src\test> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned

PS H:\src\test> . .\Get-Type.ps1
PS H:\src\test>
PS H:\src\test> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1012
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Edit 1

This appears to work as expected on 5.1.16299.98.

```
C:>. .\Get-Type.ps1
. : File C:\src\gt\Get-Type.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\src\gt\Get-Type.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run
this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . .\Get-Type.ps1
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
PS 11:13  C:\src\gt
C:>$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.98
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.98
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: I read too fast, posted an answer which refered to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/how-is-powershells-remotesigned-execution-policy-different-from-allsigned but then I noted that you already checked the ZoneID.

Comment: Maybe a bug introduced with PowerShell v5+? It works the way you expect in PowerShell v4 on Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Are you sure ZoneId=3 on Get-Type.ps1? You're referring to Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1 above (i.e. the wrong file). And what's H:? Is it a local or network location?

Comment: @PaalBraathen - Thank you for catching that. I have replaced the output in the question with the content of the Get-Type.ps1 Zone.Information ADS. Yes, H: is a mapped network drive.

Comment: @PaalBraathen - I think you are on to something. It works as expected when the .ps1 file is on a local, C:, drive. I will find some way to report this to Microsoft.